# sync a file over 2 servers and switch between what server is being connected to

Tags: scripting, synchronization

I do not know for sure if this is the correct location to post this, but I am looking for software or a script to be able to do what I am wanting... or if anyone has anything better.

In short, there is a file that gets updated on a server. I need this file to be synced with an exact duplicate on another server off site (if the file is not there it will create it). If the "primary" server goes down for this file, which I want to be able to set, then the connections to that file from an a 3rd server will automatically move to the offiste file.

I do not know if there is a product that provides this functionality. Much of what we do is written in scripts, although I personally have no scripting knowledge. Any help would be much appreciated.

If a server goes offline, then obviously the file at the other server will have the latest update. This file then has to be the one that is considered "primary" and the other file gets updated by this one. In short, the latest update always wins.

This is on Windows 2003 or windows 2008 servers.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a secure permanent connection between the two sites (vpn) then I'd look at using Distributed File System Replication (DFSR) service available in both windows server 2003 and windows server 2008. Part of the File Services Role.

[DFSR Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb540025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Replication groups and replicated folders](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759803%28WS.10%29.aspx)

[DFS Replication: Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773238%28WS.10%29.aspx)